# Google cloud - Stackdriver debug reports "File was not found in the executable" for GCE Jetty war

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform, stackdriver

I've been trying to follow the 
[Setting Up Stackdriver Debugger for Java applications on Google Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setting-up-on-compute-engine), but am running into issues with Stackdriver Debug.

I'm building my `.war` file from a separate build server, then deploying it to my GCE server. I added the agent to the start command via `/etc/defaults`, and my app appears in the `https://console.cloud.google.com/debug` control panel. The version I set in the run command matches the revision that shows up in the source-context(s).json files.

However when I click open the app, I see the message that

> No source version information was provided by the deployed application

I connected the app's git repo as a mirrored cloud repository, and can browse the source files in the sidebar of the Stackdriver Debug page. But, If I browse to a file and add a breakpoint I get an error that the error "File was not found in the executable."

I have ran the `gcloud preview app gen-repo-info-file` command, which created two basic `json` files storing my git repo and revision. Is it supposed to do anything else?

I have tried running jetty using both normal and extracted modes. If I have jetty first extract the war file, I can see the source-context.json filesin the WEB-INF/classes directory.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-debug-java#extra-classpath mentions

you can update the agentPath showing your WEB-INF/class directory.

```
-agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so=--cdbg_extra_class_path=/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes
```

For multiple class paths:

```
-agentpath:/opt/cdbg/cdbg_java_agent.so=--cdbg_extra_class_path=/opt/tomcat/webapps/myapp/WEB-INF/classes:/another/path/with/classes
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here.

First, it sounds like you are doing the correct thing with gen-repo-info-file. The debugger agent should pick up the json files from the WEB-INF/classes directory.

The debugger uses fuzzy matching to find source files, so as long as the name of the .java file matches a file in your executable, you should not get that error.

The most likely scenario given the information in your question is that you are attaching the debugger to a launcher process, rather than your actual application. Without further details, I can't absolutely confirm that, though.

If you send us more details at cdbg-feedback@google.com, we can look more closely at your case to see if we can understand exactly what's happening, and potentially improve our documentation, since it sounds like you followed the docs pretty closely.